# Feedback wanted regarding how secure this encryption/decryption is

Tags: encryption, javascript, decryption

I am creating a Password Manager and I wanted to create a JavaScript function to encrypt/decrypt data in the client-side, then I will be saving the only the encrypted data in MySQL Server. To encrypt/decrypt I am using Crypto-JS. This is what I have created so far:

HTML `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
function EncryptData(data, password){
    var iterations = 10000;
    var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8).toString();
    try {
        var password_hash = CryptoJS.SHA512(password + salt);
        var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password_hash, salt, { keySize: 512 / 32, iterations: iterations }).toString();
        var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
        var params = iterations + ':' + salt + ':' + ciphertext;
        var encoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(params));
        console.log(encoded);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Unable to encrypt data.");
    }
}

function DecryptData(data, password){
    var decoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    var iterations = decoded.split(':')[0];
    var salt = decoded.split(':')[1];
    var ciphertext = decoded.split(':')[2];
    try {
        var password_hash = CryptoJS.SHA512(password + salt);
        var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password_hash, salt, { keySize: 512 / 32, iterations: iterations }).toString();
        var cleartext = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        console.log(cleartext);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Unable to decrypt data.");
    }
}
```

### Encrypt data

`EncryptData("This is a simple demo", "abc123");`

### Decrypt data

`DecryptData("MTAwMDA6MDg3NjNiZjEwNDM1YzhkZTJkMGU2NjM5M2I1M2YxNDc6VTJGc2RHVmtYMStxZWZZSmJ2eTJHak85cTdxOS9kK2dYaCt6UHRBcjJXMEt3bE1uakNaaTY5QmVmKzA3Y1lkaw==", "abc123");`

The code works fine. I would like to read comments to know if this is secure enough (of course abc123 should be replaced by a mega secure password).

Comment: This library was useful some years ago, because there was no myna alternatives at that time. Now all major browsers support [Web Crypto API/SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto). I'd recommend you to use this API, not libraries that implement it from scratch. Usually, browser developers have more resources to properly test their functionality. That's why you can *expect* it is more reliable than solutions developed by a small community behind particular library. This is crucial for cryptographic functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is not secure for several reasons.

The crypto-js library you're using is almost two years old and seems to have been abandoned completely. The [issues keep piling up](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues), and there doesn't seem to be anyone to take care of them. I would stay away from dead software.

Cryptography in the browser also has conceptual issues and a large attack surface. First, there's no clear separation between “client-side” and “server-side”, because all the code which the client runs is dynamically provided by the server. If the server made a small change to completely break the encryption, the client likely wouldn't notice that. An attacker can also use cross-site scripting or similar attacks to mess with the client-side encryption procedure (e. g. grab the plaintext password before it's hashed).

Last but not least, [coming up with your own ad-hoc security solution is always error-prone](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own). A small mistake anywhere in the code (not necessarily in the cryptography itself) can expose all plaintext passwords and render the entire project useless.

The proper solution here is to use a well-tested, well-maintained password manager like KeePassXC, possibly together with browser plugins.

Comment: The big part of this answer is **not helpful**.

Comment: 1) *"The issues keep piling up..."* - I'd suggest to check what kind of issues these are. The most of them are *usability* issues, not security issues. In first 50 issues I see only 1 that (if confirmed) is relevant for security, it is [issue #442](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/442).

Comment: 2) *"Cryptography in the browser also has conceptual issues"* - No. This is not true.

Comment: 3) *"large attack surface"* - No. May be you mean risks related to leak of secrets. But this does not say anything about the cryptographic strength. This is determined by the algorithms (which are standard, like AES) and the quality of implementation (unless you have examples of incorrect implementation you should not do such strong statements; check all issues; if you find any weaknesses, lest us know).

Comment: 4) *"If the server made a small change"* - This statement makes no sense. A) Server and client are two parts of the solution provided by the same author (or same developers team, or same company). B) There is no logic on server that is related to encryption on the client. Server provides just assets, it is like a blob for the server. C) It is an external library. The author does not change anything in it.

Comment: 5) *"An attacker can also use cross-site scripting or similar attacks"* - This holds for *any* web application. If the application allows CORS, CSRF, XSS, obviously it is insecure itself. This has nothing to do with cryptography.

Comment: 6) *"coming up with your own ad-hoc security solution is always error-prone"* - This statement is just a **rant**. This has nothing to do with the authors code. A) The author does not implement any cryptographic algorithms. B) Usage of a public library that exist since 10 (!) years cannot be called "own ad-hoc security". C) The development of crypto-js started 2013. Web Crypto API recommendation appeared 2017, and it took some time until it was implemented.

Comment: 1) If you cannot even see the problem with using software that has been abandoned for two(!) years, I'm afraid I cannot help you here. 2) Look up supply chain security 3) Look up the OWASP Top 10 3) The entire crypto code is *provided* by the server, so any attack against (or misbehavior of) the server directly affects the client.  5) When the attack goes against the cryptography-related code, then it's an attack against the encryption.

Comment: I have no idea why you're so angry, but I think you should sleep this over and think about it for a while.

Comment: 7) *"The proper solution here is to use"* - No. It is just **your opinion**. You can say that you *recommend* to use some password manager. But stating  *"The proper solution here is to use"* is wrong, because it is just your opinion.

Comment: I am quite neutral. I see so *many* wrong statements in a *single* answer. We want to provide helpful answer. Where as *this* kind of answer leads to *irrational beliefs* in users who don't have sufficient background and who trust what the answers here.

Comment: Sorry, but you're completely misguided in this case, and recommending an approach that is demonstrably insecure shouldn't happen in a security community. As I've said, I have no idea what your problem is, but if you want a proper discussion, you should create a question and not flood people with your rants.

Comment: **Rants** are the most statements in this answer. Anyone who understands the topic should name these problems, so that others users don't accept them as truth.

Comment: You really need to calm down. As I've said, create your own question and let me or the community explain the problems in greater detail.

Comment: *"recommending an approach that is demonstrably insecure"* - This is one more **rant**. This should not happen in a security community. May be you are not aware of [Web Cryptography API](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) that is designed by W3C.

Comment: *"The entire crypto code is provided by the server, so any attack"* - Why didn't you say that any browser is insecure, because its source code is also *provided* by multiple parties (Git repo, developer patches, etc.), as well as any OS is insecure, because if smb makes malicious change, it will affect you security. This style is means just collecting anything that is *somehow* related to security but not related directly to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146138/discussion-between-ja1024-and-mentallurg).

Comment: It seems your main issue is that you think everything not directly related to cryptography is out of scope for the question and must not be considered. You see standard algorithms like AES, you see a library which you think is fine (even though it's abandoned), so you conclude the code in question is fine. I strongly disagree with this rather naive approach. Attacks against cryptography can exploit *any* weakness, not just problems with the crypto algorithms themselves. So any serious assessment must address JavaScript-related issues and the roll-your-own problem, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Interesting discussion.  WRT 'If the server made a small change to completely break the encryption, the client likely wouldn't notice that' - this is the infamous 'browser crypto chicken and egg problem'.  In other words, if the user can't trust the server with his/her secrets, then how can the user trust the server to serve secure client-side crypto code?  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238441/solution-to-the-browser-crypto-chicken-and-egg-problem for some interesting reading on this subject.